# I cannot figure out why I am getting no such instance method error

Tags: scala

This is a question regarding Coursera Scala course. Please answer why my code is not working due to the no such instance method error I get when I step the debugger through the code. The error does not stop the code from running and it always says that my filtered tweetSet is empty but it should include the Tom and Mike Tweet. The specific error at

```
val foo = temp.filter(_.retweets > 4)

TrueTweet = No such instance method: 'objsets.test$$anonfun$2.trueTweet '
No such instance method: 'objsets.test$$anonfun$2.objsets$test$$trueTweet '
temp = No such instance method: 'objsets.test$$anonfun$2.temp '
No such instance method: 'objsets.test$$anonfun$2.objsets$test$$temp '
falseTweet = No such instance method: 'objsets.test$$anonfun$2.falseTweet '
No such instance method: 'objsets.test$$anonfun$2.objsets$test$$falseTweet '
```

my `Test` class

```
class Test extends FunSuite {
  val trueTweet = new Tweet("Tom", "Hello", 45)
  val falseTweet = new Tweet("Mike", "HellO", 44)
  var temp: TweetSet = new NonEmpty(new Tweet("Jon", "I am the best", 2), new Empty(), new Empty())
  temp = temp.incl(trueTweet)
  temp = temp.incl(falseTweet)

  def printFunc(t: Tweet): Unit = {
    println(t)
  }

  val foo = temp.filter(_.retweets > 4)
  foo.foreach(printFunc)
}
```

part of the `TweetSet` class

```
class TweetSet {
  def filter(p: Tweet => Boolean): TweetSet = filterAcc(p, new Empty)
}
```

`Tweet` class

```
class Tweet(val user: String, val text: String, val retweets: Int) {
  override def toString: String =
    "User: " + user + "\n" + "Text: " + text + " [" + retweets + "]"
}
```

part of the `Empty` class

```
class Empty extends TweetSet {
  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = this

  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit = ()
}
```

part of the `NonEmpty` class

```
class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet {
  def filterAcc(p: Tweet => Boolean, acc: TweetSet): TweetSet = {
    var accHelper = acc
    foreach(t => if (p(t)) accHelper.incl(t))
    accHelper
  }

  def foreach(f: Tweet => Unit): Unit = {
    f(elem)
    left.foreach(f)
    right.foreach(f)
  }

 def incl(x: Tweet): TweetSet = {
    if (x.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)
    else if (elem.text < x.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
    else this
 }
}
```

Comment: can you fix your snippets so that it applies to scala style guide?

Comment: I am a little new to this so I am not really sure what you would like changed.  I made some small changes I hope I at least addressed some of your issues.

Comment: Your code was just ugly and hard to read. I can't really test the code without incl method. What I can tell you now, is that your `filterAcc` implementation for `NonEmpty` is probably not what you want to do. If incl returns a new `TweetSet` you are discarding it everytime in foreach, you might want to reasign it to var each time. You should not use vars + foreach as it's very imperative. Anyway why don't you ask on coursera forums? People in there for sure at least know the context.

Comment: I would ask on coursera but the class is well over.  No one is looking at it.
How is foreach discarding, it returns nothing.  Also, how are you getting that highlight on things such as filterAcc and NonEmpty

Comment: to highlight use backticks ``` If your `TweetSet` should be immutable, then asuming `incl` is inserting something, it should return a new `TweetSet` with  the value inserted. Your `foreach(t => if (p(t)) accHelper.incl(t))` in your code `accHelper.incl(t)` would produce a new TweetSet but you will ignore that and again insert another element to original acc. You might want to do `foreach(t => if (p(t)) accHelper = accHelper.incl(t))`

Comment: ow and by the way your test is wrong, just noticed obvious thing http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_fun_suite you should wrap your code inside `Test` into `test("whatever are you testing") { your code here }`

Comment: you were right about 'foreach(t => if (p(t)) accHelper = accHelper.incl(t))'
that was a dumb mistake that I should have cought.  I also agree with you about the setup.  It now gives me the proper answer.  It still says that stuff when I run the debugger but I guess there not really errors.  Thanks for the help.  I would checkbox that you gave the right answer but I can't the way you responded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test class is wrong, refer to http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_fun_suite to see how it should be set up.

```
class Test extends FunSuite {
  test("what are you testing") {
    val trueTweet = new Tweet("Tom", "Hello", 45)
    val falseTweet = new Tweet("Mike", "HellO", 44)
    var temp: TweetSet = new NonEmpty(new Tweet("Jon", "I am the best", 2), new Empty(), new Empty())
    temp = temp.incl(trueTweet)
    temp = temp.incl(falseTweet)

    def printFunc(t: Tweet): Unit = {
      println(t)
    }

    val foo = temp.filter(_.retweets > 4)
    foo.foreach(printFunc)
  }

  test("what are you testing") {
    //other test code
  }
}
```